# Need help on a example about proof on functions and sets

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I need some help to prove the problem below:

Suppose $g$ is a function from $X$ to $Y$ and $f$ is a function from $Y$ to $Z$. $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$.
Prove that if $A$ is a subset of $B$ then $f\circ g(A)$ is also a subset of $f\circ g(B)$.

I learned sets and functions years ago but I have never encountered a proof problem about them. I'm not sure if it is too easy or not but I have no idea about how to prove this kind of a problem.

Could you please provide me some help and solution example to move on this subject further more?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually when you want to prove that one set is a subset of another, you take an arbitrary element of it ($x$), and show that it's in the other set.
(Another strategy in this case would be to first show that $g(A) \subseteq g(B)$)

Answer (score 0):

$A \subseteq B$ means that for all $x \in A$ you have that $x \in B$. $f \circ g(A) = \{ f(g(x)) : x \in A\}$, while $f \circ g(B) = \{ f(g(x)) : x \in B\}$.

Finally, if you pick any element $z \in f \circ g(A)$ it is of the form $z = f(g(x))$ for some $x \in A$. Since $x \in B$, you have that $z = f(g(x)) \in \{ f(g(x)) : x \in B\} = f \circ g(B)$.

So $f \circ g(A) \subseteq f \circ g(B)$.